# Alternative to CTE for Limiting a Running Total

Tags: ssis, common-table-expression

Before I get into the technical details, I should explain the scenario.  I have table that contains a list of work orders due on particular dates.  These work orders are for pallets of product and a work order can contain 1 pallet or multiple pallets.  I need to get a list of work orders where the running total of pallets is equal to or just slightly greater than a fixed number (like 10 pallets).  Since work orders cannot be split, if the pallet count is reached on a work order for multiple pallets, the work order number should be included.

For example, assume I have 10 pallets where (in order) the quantities are 2,3,1,2,5,1,1,2,3,1.  I would return the first 5 records since 2+3+1+2+5=13 (13 being the first total equal to or over 10).

Sorry about the long blurb, but I wanted to make my scenario clear from a math perspective.

I have created this CTE, which technically works:

```
DECLARE @r INT = 10;--Set the limit of number of pallets

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT TOP 100 WONumber --Get only a sample of records.
        ,PalletCount
        ,RunningID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY [Sequence Complete Date]
                ,WONumber
            )
    FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[TableName]
    WHERE ShuttleStatus IS NULL --Get pallets not already captured.
    )
SELECT WONumber
    ,PalletCount
FROM CTE AS A
WHERE (
        SELECT SUM(PalletCount)
        FROM CTE
        WHERE RunningID < A.RunningID
        ) < @r --Limit to a specific number of pallets
    OR A.RunningID = 1
```

However, it is pretty slow (5-10 seconds), considering that the table contains less than 1000 records and I am already limiting it to 100 in the query.

At this point, I am looking for any suggestions how I could accomplish this more efficiently.  I have some experience in SSIS and I am willing to do it there.  However, I can't figure out how to do this without resorting to a script task, which gets somewhat messy.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.  Thank you!

Comment: The good news is the 2012 release of SQL Server allows for much more graceful implementation to running sums problems. You might get better performance on your query depending on whether ShuttleSTatus and `Sequence Complete Date` are indexed, without seeing query plans and such, it's just a guess. Your SSIS solution would look like what, pull all the data out of TableName and do the running sums in memory?

Comment: Billnkc - Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately (as you probably guessed) I still on SQL 20008 R2, so I can't take advantage of those new methods.  My SSIS solution would be a script task that kept a running total in a variable, keeping a list of Work Order Numbers.  It would exit when my limit was reached.  Does that sound like the best way?  Thanks again for your feedback.